# GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR by using LWJGL

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl, apple-m1

I just set up LWJGL 3 in Eclipse and I wanted to test it with the [example code](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide).
This is the output that I get:

```java
Hello LWJGL 3.2.3 build 13!
[LWJGL] GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR error
    Description : Cocoa: Failed to find service port for display
    Stacktrace  :
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit(GLFW.java:830)
        my.lwjgltests.HelloWorld.init(HelloWorld.java:42)
        my.lwjgltests.HelloWorld.run(HelloWorld.java:24)
        my.lwjgltests.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:114)
[LWJGL] GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR error
    Description : Cocoa: Failed to find service port for display
    Stacktrace  :
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit(GLFW.java:830)
        my.lwjgltests.HelloWorld.init(HelloWorld.java:42)
        my.lwjgltests.HelloWorld.run(HelloWorld.java:24)
        my.lwjgltests.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:114)
```

By the way, I'm on macOS Big Sur with an M1 chip, so maybe it's a problem?

Edit:
I have another Mac from 2012 with macOS Catalina, and everything seems to work properly.

Edit 2:
Since I have two monitors, I tried with only one and got just one of the two errors above. So maybe I should find a way to "bind" the program to the monitors since it outputs "Failed to find service port for display"?

Comment: The example code works fine on my end. You are better off creating an issue on here: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so apparently the problem was pretty obvious: GLFW is just not available on Apple M1 yet.

[GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR on the GLFW documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__errors.html#gad44162d78100ea5e87cdd38426b8c7a1)